# White powder on parts under car bonnet

Tags: honda, civic

I have recently ( 3days back) purchased a used car, Honda civic in ohio US. I have noticed white powder on parts under bonnet. Attached is the picture. Is it a concern? What should I do? I am really worried, please advice. Its 2015 Honda Civic SE
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's light corrosion deposits from moisture or the detergent the cleaners used. Cleaning it off with a brush should work.

Not a problem unless the pits start to go all the way through or make big holes in the components...

Comment: Yes, very typical for aluminum ... I'm sure it's just aluminum (or aluminium) oxide.

Comment: Big holes!!! You are scaring me. So should I confront the dealer about it? How can I remove this permanently  so that it does not damage the parts ?

Comment: To get big holes you'll need about another 40 years... It's fine - seen it so often before. You can clean it off and either lightly oil it or leave it dry.